# Read-Ahead cache for scrolling over large file

Tags: java, caching, scroll

I'm scrolling over a large text file that contains a lot of records and each record takes multiple lines in the file. All this works fine. However to improve performance I would like some kind of read-ahead cache (that also works when scrolling up).

Basically it should automatically cache a certain amount before and after the current record but not each scroll operation should trigger a cache change. Meaning only after a certain limit is reached, the cache is shifted.

I'm kind of stuck on how to manage such a cache, eg., when to trigger a read-ahead. I can use ehcache with LRU. LRU should automatically evict the correct entires. Question then remains how to manage when to evict.

Looking for general ideas, language is Java.

Comment: What sort of processing is happening at the cursor? How far ahead do you want to read? When to trigger a read-ahead is going to depend on how fast the processing is happening.  If your processing is sequential I'm not sure the added complexity of managing a cache will provide sufficient benefit over just using a large read buffer.  Without much more detailed information this question is not answerable in any meaningful way.

Comment: You might look into the RandomAccessFile class, you could define a cache start and cache length then shift the cache upon request and append to the start or end. But like @JimGarrison mentioned without knowing more details it is hard to provide a actual solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)?

Ignoring the circular part for the moment (it doesn't draw so nicely)...

Starting off:

```
---------- entire buffered contents ---------
|       ---- no reload threshold ----       |
|       |      current display      |       |
|       |     |               |     |       |
```

As long as the `current display` is within the `no reload threshold`, don't do anything, but once we reach the no reload threshold:

```
---------- entire buffered contents ---------
|       ---- no reload threshold ----       |
|       current display             |       |
|      ||              |            |       |
```

Discard stuff on the right, load more stuff on the left and shift the no reload threshold so we have a picture exactly like the first one.

Well, actually you probably don't have to discard stuff on the right right away, it might be wise to keep it around until it shifts more to the left, just in case the user shift back to the right instead (then you already have the data loaded), but, in that case, you could've just had a bigger buffer, so maybe just discard it.

Here 'left' and 'right' are 'down' and 'up', or 'up' and 'down'.

You'd have to play around with the buffer size and threshold.

Answer (score 0):

While thinking out loud...

Say you keep a count of how many bytes you have read and how many bytes are visible currently.

That is to have two buffers for before and after cursor/view. As you scroll down the buffer_after cursor decreases by the number of bytes you have shown on the screen.

And when the size of buffer_after reaches a certain low number you trigger the read ahead and fill the buffer.